# Send E-Mail Using VBA To E-Mail Lists On Excel

Tags: email, vba, outlook

*ve 90% of my VBA code written, just need to add the following. My macro pretty much runs and If Statement and if a certain condition applies, it will email it to a certain address. What I need it to do is to run the if statement, and if it meets the certain condition to email it to a list of 4-5 emails (maybe even more) which is in the same workbook but a different tab entitled "Email List".*

---

You can ignore the top part, this is what I'm currently working on.

This is the updated code. Please advise as there are 8 sections so how will I transfer the Email code you came up with for the next 7? Thanks in advance man, really appreciate all your help.

```
Sub Send_Range()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim i As Long

    row = Sheets("Email List").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    col = Sheets("Email List").UsedRange.Columns.Count

    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B4")) Then
        With Sheets("Email List")
            For Each rCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, col))
                If rCell.Value <> "" Then
                    For i = 3 To row
                        If .Cells(i, rCell.Column).Value <> "" Then
                            SendTo = SendTo & .Cells(i, rCell.Column + 1).Value & ";"
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If

   If IsEmpty(Range("B4")) Then
   Else
      ActiveSheet.Range("a3", ActiveSheet.Range("e3").End(xlDown)).Select
      ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope

      .Item.To = SendTo
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations -  Barclays" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If

       row = Sheets("Email List").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    col = Sheets("Email List").UsedRange.Columns.Count

    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B4")) Then
        With Sheets("Email List")
            For Each rCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, col))
                If rCell.Value <> "" Then
                    For i = 3 To row
                        If .Cells(i, rCell.Column).Value <> "" Then
                            SendTo = SendTo & .Cells(i, rCell.Column + 1).Value & ";"
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If

   If IsEmpty(Range("H4")) Then
   Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("G3", ActiveSheet.Range("K3").End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "alulla@bluemountaincapital.com" & "; alulla92@outlook.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations - BNP" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If

      If IsEmpty(Range("N4")) Then
   Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("M3", ActiveSheet.Range("Q3").End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "alulla@bluemountaincapital.com" & "; alulla92@outlook.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations - CITINY" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If

   If IsEmpty(Range("T4")) Then
   Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("S3", ActiveSheet.Range("W3").End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "alulla@bluemountaincapital.com" & "; alulla92@outlook.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations - CSFB" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If

      If IsEmpty(Range("Z4")) Then
   Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("Y3", ActiveSheet.Range("AC3").End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "alulla@bluemountaincapital.com" & "; alulla92@outlook.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations - DB" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If

      If IsEmpty(Range("AF4")) Then
   Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("AE3", ActiveSheet.Range("AI3").End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "alulla@bluemountaincapital.com" & "; alulla92@outlook.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations - JPM" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If

      If IsEmpty(Range("AL4")) Then
   Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("AK3", ActiveSheet.Range("AO3").End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "alulla@bluemountaincapital.com" & "; alulla92@outlook.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations - MS" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If

      If IsEmpty(Range("AR4")) Then
   Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("AQ3", ActiveSheet.Range("AU3").End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "alulla@bluemountaincapital.com" & "; alulla92@outlook.com"
      .Item.Subject = "Allocations - " & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple emails can be sent by separating addresses with a semicolon.

```
Email "email@example.com;email2@example.com", Subject:=:Example Email", Body:="Example Mail"
```

You can search your sheet containing emails for the set of emails you need to send mail to, add each email to a string with a semicolon between each one.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim i As Long

    For Each rCell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        If rCell.Value = "DNP" Then
            For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If Cells(i, rCell.Column).Value <> "" Then
                    SendTo = SendTo & Cells(i, rCell.Column + 1).Value & ";"
                End If
            Next
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Email SendTo
End Sub
```

You can send emails using the following:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Desc  : Sends an email
' Ex    : Email SendTo:=email@example.com, Subject:="example email", Body:="Email Body"
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Email(SendTo As String, Optional CC As String, Optional BCC As String, Optional Subject As String, Optional Body As String, Optional Attachment As Variant)
    Dim s As Variant              'Attachment string if array is passed
    Dim Mail_Object As Variant    'Outlook application object
    Dim Mail_Single As Variant    'Email object

    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

    With Mail_Single
        'Add attachments
        Select Case TypeName(Attachment)
            Case "Variant()"
                For Each s In Attachment
                    If s <> Empty Then
                        If FileExists(s) = True Then
                            Mail_Single.attachments.Add s
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Case "String"
                If Attachment <> Empty Then
                    If FileExists(Attachment) = True Then
                        Mail_Single.attachments.Add Attachment
                    End If
                End If
        End Select

        'Setup email
        .Subject = Subject
        .To = SendTo
        .CC = CC
        .BCC = BCC
        .HTMLbody = Body
        On Error GoTo SEND_FAILED
        .Send
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Exit Sub

SEND_FAILED:
    With Mail_Single
        MsgBox "Mail to '" & .To & "' could not be sent."
        .Delete
    End With
    Resume Next
End Sub

Function FileExists(ByVal Path As String) As Boolean
    'Remove trailing backslash
    If InStr(Len(Path), Path, "\") > 0 Then Path = Left(Path, Len(Path) - 1)
    'Check to see if the directory exists and return true/false
    If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> "" Then FileExists = True
End Function
```

-Edit- This will get all of the emails

```
Sub Send_Range()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim i As Long

    row = Sheets("Email List").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    col = Sheets("Email List").UsedRange.Columns.Count

    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B4")) Then
        With Sheets("Email List")
            For Each rCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, col))
                If rCell.Value <> "" Then
                    For i = 3 To row
                        If .Cells(i, rCell.Column).Value <> "" Then
                            SendTo = SendTo & .Cells(i, rCell.Column + 1).Value & ";"
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
        SendTo = Left(SendTo, Len(SendTo) - 1)
        .Item.To = SendTo
        .Item.Subject = "Allocations - Barclays" & Format(Date, " mm/dd/yyyy")
        .Item.Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I currently have a code which works 99% but is just missing the first email of every list. Please advise if you can.

Comment: The `Sub Example` should work to get every email. I made an excel sheet to mirror the image you posted and tested it against that.

Comment: Hey Ripster, I appreciate the help. But I have gotten so far and think the code I just updated my original post with just needs a little bit of tweaking. Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: Wait this doesn't work for some reason, it isn't attaching the table that I originally planned to attach.

Comment: Okay fixed it for the first table, just curious as to how I will edit this for the rest of the 8 email lists (within same worksheet) and will I have to Dim more rows cols and rCells, etc? or can i just reuse it

Comment: Within the same worksheet or workbook? You may want to post an example to clarify.

Comment: Just updated my original post, we are very close lol. Pretty much the other eight are in the same worksheet as the first table which I'm emailling. And the other email lists are in the same worksheet as the other Email list but just instead of B3, is in E3, and then H3, etc etc.

Comment: Anyone? Still stuck on this :(